# broken packages occur when to install aptitude in debian

Tags: linux, debian, packages, aptitude

I want to install aptitude in my latest debian10.0.4(host is debian9,virtual machine in the host is debian10.0.4):

```
sudo apt-get install  aptitude
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.1) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

To install the dependences:

```
sudo apt-get install  libapt-pkg5.0   libparse-debianchangelog-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapt-pkg5.0 is already the newest version (1.8.2).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libparse-debianchangelog-perl : Depends: libclass-accessor-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

To install the dependence:

```
sudo apt install  libclass-accessor-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libclass-accessor-perl : Depends: libsub-name-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Go on to install dependence:

```
sudo apt install    libsub-name-perl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsub-name-perl : Depends: perlapi-5.24.1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Go on to install :

```
sudo apt install  perlapi-5.24.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package perlapi-5.24.1 is a virtual package provided by:
  perl-base 5.24.1-3+deb9u5 [Not candidate version]
  perl-base 5.24.1-3+deb9u6 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'perlapi-5.24.1' has no installation candidate
```

How to solve the issue then?

Comment: looks like you were using Debian 9 and did not fully upgrade to Debian 10. You'll have to give more informations about what you did or did not when going from Debian 9 to Debian 10 in the past. libsub-name-perl should depend on perlapi-5.28.0 on a properly installed Debian 10. Your new goal is not to install aptitude but to complete the upgrade to Debian 10.

Comment: host is debian9,virtual machine in the host is debian10.0.4

Comment: Maybe, but this doesn't change the problem, somehow somewere there were mixups between debian 9 and debian 10 done. This could even be in the question you wrote (if you sometimes cut/paste commands from host, sometimes from vm)

Comment: I am sure that all info shown in this post are all in my virtual machine's debian10.